# Unity how to find if object intersects with mesh collider (not bounding box, the actual mesh)?

Tags: unity-game-engine

i know how to detect basic bounding box collisions

```
 Collider collider1= obj1.GetComponent<Collider>();
 Collider collider2= obj2.GetComponent<Collider>();
 if (collider1.bounds.Intersects(collider2.bounds))
                     Debug.Log("collides with=" + objCollider.name);
```

but that's not very accurate, i'd like to get if their actual meshes collide so i tried

```
 MeshCollider collider1= obj1.GetComponent<MeshCollider>();
  MeshCollider collider2= obj2.GetComponent<MeshCollider>();
  if (collider1.bounds.Intersects(collider2.bounds))
         Debug.Log("collides with=" + objCollider.name);
```

and no difference, any suggestions please?

thanks

UPDATE, please note i forgot to add that i need this to work when timescale is zero and collisions don't work then

Comment: You could generate a mesh collider component which matches the actual mesh. But it is likely to create a lot of unnecessary points and will require computation if you have many objects.

Comment: Why do you need this to be accurate? And how accurate do you need it??
Collisions are not simple and are one of the most difficult things for the engine to do. Also, take care about using mesh colliders.. they are computationally heavy.

Comment: is stackoverflow the right community for this? what about asking this on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ ? maybe you get better answeres, from people developing games.

Comment: ok, i'll try gamedev.stackexchange.com next, thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's not the correct way to detect collisions. Use `MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter` or  `MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter` instead.

> [`OnTriggerEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html) is called when the Collider other enters the trigger.
>
> [`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html) is called when this collider/rigidbody has begun touching another rigidbody/collider.

Just attach the following script to the `GameObject` that will collide with another `GameObject`. The method will be called when the collision happens.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) // or void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add that i need this to work when timescale is zero and collisions don't work then.